# How to remove old devices from FMAudit Onsite?

Tags: network-printer

If you use FMAudit to collect printer usage data it will accumulate junk devices over time. Not just old printers but it picks up many things that respond to SNMP query.

As of version 4.1.3 the GUI still doesn't offer an option to remove old devices! The only forum post I can find talking about this issue says the solution is to reinstall. That doesn't sound ideal.

How do I remove old devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information it collects is stored in an MSAccess database found in the program folder:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\FMAuditOnsite\Web\App_Data\Data.mdb"`

That DB file is password protected to keep out people who don't know how to safely edit an Access DB. If that's you, stop reading now. If you're feeling froggy, you can use [accesspv](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/accesspv.html) to show you the password.

1. Stop the `FMAuditOnsite` service
2. If it hangs, kill the process
3. Make a backup copy of the DB file
4. Open it with MSAccess
5. Edit the `Printers` table by deleting the old records
6. Restart the `FMAuditOnsite` service

I recommend keeping the network scan IP range very small as to only cover your printers. This will prevent junk from showing up on the next scan.